# css при масштабировании правый блок уползает вниз

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

почему, когда я уменьшаю масштаб - ссылка 9 ссылка 10 ссылка 11 ссылка 12 уползают вниз, и как это можно исправить?

и еще хотелось как то ограничить canvas. чтоб его вертикальный размер масштабировался, а не вытягивался на всю странцу

```css
body {
background: #333333;
color: #000000;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman;
font-size: 12px;
}
table {border-spacing: 7px 11px;
  border:0px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  border: 0px solid #0095ff;
}
a {
   white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

canvas{ color: #ff55ff;
background-color: #001100;
float: left;
width: 67%;
height:  100%;
margin: 1%;
border-radius:10px; border: 0px solid #333333;
}

#TOPmenu{width: 100%;}
#Lmenu{width: 12%; float:left; margin: 1%;}
#Rmenu{width: 12%; float:right;margin: 1%;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="unico.css" />
</head>



<table id="TOPmenu" width="500">
<tr>
    <td><a href="1">ссылка 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="2">ссылка 2</a></td>
    <td><a href="3">ссылка 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="4">ссылка 4</a></td>
</tr>
</table>


<div id="menu">
 <table id="Lmenu" width="500" border=1>
<tr>
  <tr><td><a href="1">ссылка 5</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="2">ссылка 6</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="3">ссылка 7</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="4">ссылка 8</a></td></tr>
</tr>
</table>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
 
 <table id="Rmenu" width="500" border=1>
<tr>
  <tr><td><a href="1">ссылка 9</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="2">ссылка 10</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="3">ссылка 11</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="4">ссылка 12</a></td></tr>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

id="Rmenu" - у вас ориентирован на выравнивание справа и если он не влазит, то сползет соответственно вниз и выровняется справа float:right;. 
Забудьте о float, так уже не верстают, используйте display: inline-block или inline-flex, inline, они выстроят объекты в линию.
canvas у вас вытягивается width: 67%; в html ширина превалирует над высотой, задайте фиксированную ширину в px, тогда вложимое canvas будет растягивать его в высоту, а ширина будет неизменной.

Comment: Юрий, вы как почти всегда правы. Добавил ответ по вашему ответу

Comment: в вашем коде Yuri  - font-size: 2vw; vw - плохо использовать для шрифта, лучше em, так как vw - зависит от ширины окна браузера, а em - от родительского блока и увеличению или уменьшению подвержен меньше

Comment: Юрий, это пусть уже он исправляет. Я ответил на его вопрос

Answer (score 1):

И не используйте больше table, пожалуйста

```css
body {
background: #333333;
color: #000000;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman;
font-size: 12px;
}
table {border-spacing: 7px 11px;
  border:0px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  border: 0px solid #0095ff;
}
a {
   white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
/* Добавляем это */
#menu {
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%;
}

/* Меняем тут */
canvas { 
  color: #ff55ff;
  background-color: #001100;
  height:  100%;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius:10px; border: 0px solid #333333;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Ещё добавляем это */
}

#TOPmenu{width: 100%;}
#Lmenu{display: block; margin: 1%;} /* Изменяем это */
#Rmenu{display: block; margin: 1%;} /* И это */
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="unico.css" />
</head>



<table id="TOPmenu" width="500">
<tr>
    <td><a href="1">ссылка 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="2">ссылка 2</a></td>
    <td><a href="3">ссылка 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="4">ссылка 4</a></td>
</tr>
</table>


<div id="menu">
 <table id="Lmenu" width="500" border=1>
<tr>
  <tr><td><a href="1">ссылка 5</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="2">ссылка 6</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="3">ссылка 7</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="4">ссылка 8</a></td></tr>
</tr>
</table>

 <canvas id="canvas" height="500" ;></canvas>
 
 <table id="Rmenu" width="500" border=1>
<tr>
  <tr><td><a href="1">ссылка 9</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="2">ссылка 10</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="3">ссылка 11</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="4">ссылка 12</a></td></tr>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```